Obstacle avoidance in opennav_coverage Nav2
I am working on coverage path planner using opennav_coverage for ROS2 Humble from Navigation2. Currently, when an obstacle occurs on a robot path then coverage_server is stopping and doesn't continue the job. It's reasonable since there are different ways of handling this kind of situation as noted in the github issue. I would like to ask if my approach is correct or if I should choose a different way of solving this problem. I would like to achive that if a robot is blocked, then replan around the obstacle to get back on the coverage path. I created an action BT plugin which:

subscribe the global costmap and a robot footprint and get a planned coverage path as an input
transform footprint to each path pose (with orientation) and check if the points inside footprint will be in collision (value of 100 in costmap)
delete from path a poses with collision

Then in BT the logic is going to be:

if the obstacle in front of the robot then (slow down) wait 5 seconds
if the obstacle is still there run the collision solving plugin
plan the path to the first point in the filtered path and continue the job

Robot won't always see where is the end of the obstacle (it could be some kind of a long object). Then it should still work, the robot will plan the path to some point. Then follow a path to this point and if the obstacle size is big and it cannot finish then running the plugin again should make the robot going back to the coverage path.
I would be thankful for advice before I will go deeper to that solution if there is any different, easier and correct way of solving that with nav2 stack.
Current fragment from my code:
BT::NodeStatus RemoveInCollisionGoals::tick()
{
  rclcpp::spin_some(node_);

  getInput("cost_threshold", cost_threshold_);
  getInput("input_path", input_path_); 
  //setOutput("output_path", input_path_); Here will be the filtered path

  input_goals_ = input_path_.poses;
  RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "TEST NODE");
  if (input_goals_.empty()) {
    setOutput("output_path", input_path_);
    RCLCPP_ERROR(node_->get_logger(), "Input path is empty");
    return BT::NodeStatus::FAILURE;
  }
  if(map_initialized_ && footprint_initialized_){
    // PoseStamped (position + orientation). Tranform footprint to the frame of next poses 
    // and check if the points inside footprint collide
  }
  return BT::NodeStatus::SUCCESS;
}

